# Error during template rendering ProgrammingError at /admin/ column django_content_type.name does not exist

Tags: django, apache2, virtualenv, wsgi

I am trying to upgrade form 1.7.4 to 1.8 and higher. Trying to go one step at a time.

All steps are done except I am not able to open main admin page.

I am able to open apps in the admin. But not the main admin template.

Here is the error:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/
column django_content_type.name does not exist
LINE 1: ..._user"."date_joined", "django_content_type"."id", "django_co...
                                                             ^
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://test.shipler.in/admin/
Django Version: 1.7.4
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
column django_content_type.name does not exist
LINE 1: ..._user"."date_joined", "django_content_type"."id", "django_co...


                                                       ^
```

It is the causing error while template rendering

```
Error during template rendering

In template /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html, error at line 63
column django_content_type.name does not exist LINE 1: ..._user"."date_joined", "django_content_type"."id", "django_co... ^
53  <div id="content-related">
54      <div class="module" id="recent-actions-module">
55          <h2>{% trans 'Recent Actions' %}</h2>
56          <h3>{% trans 'My Actions' %}</h3>
57              {% load log %}
58              {% get_admin_log 10 as admin_log for_user user %}
59              {% if not admin_log %}
60              <p>{% trans 'None available' %}</p>
61              {% else %}
62              <ul class="actionlist">
63              **{% for entry in admin_log %}**
64              <li class="{% if entry.is_addition %}addlink{% endif %}{% if entry.is_change %}changelink{% endif %}{% if entry.is_deletion %}deletelink{% endif %}">
65                  {% if entry.is_deletion or not entry.get_admin_url %}
66                      {{ entry.object_repr }}
67                  {% else %}
68                      <a href="{{ entry.get_admin_url }}">{{ entry.object_repr }}</a>
69                  {% endif %}
70                  <br/>
71                  {% if entry.content_type %}
72                      <span class="mini quiet">{% filter capfirst %}{% trans entry.content_type.name %}{% endfilter %}</span>
73                  {% else %}
```

**{% for entry in admin_log %}** Is causing a problem.

It is showing django 1.7.4 but I already upgraded to 1.8.9 but some how its still using 1.7.4

Its happening on remote server but locally its working fine.

Please let me know what is the problem here?

Regards

**EDIT**

Django Version out side the environment is 1.7.4 and Inside it is 1.8.12.

It seems that the admin is trying to use from outside the environment.

**EDIT 2**

After a lot of research found out that the virtual environment which the project is pointing to is different, where the django verison is 1.7.

I changed the path of virtual environment in the wsgi file inside project.

But now it is giving

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

Kindly help out.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you are in your virtual enviroment, then run pip install django==1.8.14
then your error indicates that there are columns missing, so run migrations

`./manage.py migrate`

Comment: Yes, done it couple of times.

Inside environment. 
Installed django after stoping apache
And ran the migrate command

Still the problem persists. 

It is still using django 1.7.4

Comment: More research shows that Django Version out side the environment is 1.7.4 and Inside it is 1.8.12.

It seems that the admin is trying to use from outside the environment.